# Trying to build a random number guessing game but print statements are tripping me up

Tags: python

I'm completely new to python as of 2 weeks ago. I'm trying to build a random number guessing game. If the guess is wrong, I want the system to return if the number is higher or lower but I keep getting either number is lower or higher repeated over and over. If the guess it right, it says I lost.

```
import random

random_number = random.randint(0,10)
guess = int
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 5
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != random_number and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = (int(input("Enter guess: ")))
        guess_count += 1
    if guess < random_number: 
        print("Number is higher")
    if guess > random_number:
        print("Number is lower")
    
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("Out of guesses, YOU SUCK!")
else:
    print("You win")
```

Comment: You never check if guess does equal the random number

Answer (score 1):

```
if guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = (int(input("Enter guess: ")))
    guess_count += 1
if guess < random_number: 
    print("Number is higher")
if guess > random_number:
    print("Number is lower")

else:
    out_of_guesses = True
```

In this sample your else statement refers back to the last "if", that means that if your guess is not higher than random_number, it will always set out_of_guesses to true.

I don't want to spoil the answer since learning python is a fun experience. I would read up a bit more on control flow in python. [This](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-in-a/0596001886/ch04s09.html) could be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Just indent the `guess ... random number` statements:

```
import random

random_number = random.randint(0,10)
guess = int
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 5
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != random_number and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = int(input("Enter guess: "))
        guess_count += 1
        if guess < random_number: 
            print("Number is higher")
        if guess > random_number:
            print("Number is lower")
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("Out of guesses, YOU SUCK!")
else:
    print("You win")
```

Answer (score 0):

So, at this moment, you don't have the right identation. The `else` statement as it is right now will connect with `if guess > random_number:`
This means that if the `guess` is lower then `random_number` than `out_of_guesses` will become `True`, because the logic is the following:

```
if guess > random_number: # This returns False
else # This will happen if the guess is not grater then random_number
out_of_guesses = True
```

So your code should look like this:

```
import random

random_number = random.randint(0,10)
guess = int
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 5
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != random_number and not(out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = (int(input("Enter guess: ")))
        guess_count += 1
        if guess < random_number: 
            print("Number is higher")
        if guess > random_number:
            print("Number is lower")
    
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("Out of guesses, YOU SUCK!")
else:
    print("You win")
```